# How to create a Python 'alarm' which will act either today or tomorrow

Tags: python, datetime

I have been given a python script which allows me to mute the volume of my mac at a time I set so that any podcasts I'm listening to as I fall asleep won't wake me up once I am asleep.

However, it will only act once the time given happens on that day, therefore if I try to activate it before midnight, it will mute the laptop immediately, which is not ideal because if I want to use it I have to wait for midnight to pass before I go to sleep.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import datetime as dt
import osascript
import sys
from threading import Timer 

def do_the_biz():
   osascript.osascript("set volume output volume 0")
   print("Night night")
today = dt.datetime.now()
dateString = today.strftime('%d-%m-%Y') + " " + sys.argv[1]
newDate = today.strptime(dateString,'%d-%m-%Y %H:%M')
delay = (newDate - dt.datetime.now()).total_seconds()
Timer(delay,do_the_biz,()).start()
```

So, a typical execution of this script looks like this:

```
$./sleep.py 04:00
```

and the command line will return the following once it has reached 4am, and then close the program:

```
Night Night
```

What I would like is to be able to manipulate the date so that the script will operate at the next available time of, for example, 4am - so it would essentially operate almost in the exact same way an alarm would. For this I could run an entirely different script of sleep.tomorrow.

However, in an ideal world, I would like to be able to:

- have the option to have another argument where I specify today or tomorrow and the program acts accordingly;
- be able to cancel the process without having to close the terminal.

I am new to python and have been having a hard time understanding the differences between the various datetime functions and the documention hasn't helped, so a brief explanation and comparison between what they input and output and how they interact would be gratefully appreciated.

Comment: Use `crontab` as an `os` call.  Compute the desired execution time from your command-line arguments and "simple" datetime math, and set the go_to_sleep job to fire off at that time.

Comment: Add this line before delay line `if dt.datetime.now() > newDate: newDate += dt.timedelta(days=1)`. It will check whether the mentioned time has passed. If true it set alarm to next day. Check [this](https://repl.it/repls/GlossyCoralEmbeds) to understand the difference this line makes to your script.